# requirejs - combine several files to single js file that not dependent on requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, require, minify

I am writing jQuery plugin that contains a lot of code. Therefore I decided to separate the code and make it more modular for me (the developer). For this I use require.js.
Now I have 6 js files:

1. utils.js
2. base-row.jas
3. a-row.js
4. b-row.js
5. my-table.js
6. main.js

Files 1 to 5 defines JavaScript "classes" and they have dependecies between themselves. The "primary" class that operates all the concert is my-table.js. main.js has dependency only to my-table.js and creates a plugin from it:

```
require([
    'my-table'
], function(MyTable) {
    jQuery.fn.myTable = function(options) {
        var table = new MyTable(this, options);
        this.data('myTable', table);
        return this;
    };
});
```

Now I want to create from those files one big js file that contains all the 6 files without any dependency (except jQuery that the user should put reference to it). For this I used r.js (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) and as a result I got one big js file that depend on require.js (and contains calls to define and require). I followed this: http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-optimization.html#wrap and used almond.js in order to combined all my files for usage that is not dependent on require.js. This works fine.
The problem is why do I need all the define and require method calls and almond.js? Why couldn't the optimizer concatenate only the function results (as describe in this question: [Why do concatenated RequireJS AMD modules need a loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987674/why-do-concatenated-requirejs-amd-modules-need-a-loader)) like this:

```
(function() {
    var utils = «function() {
        ....
        return Utils;
    }»();
    var baseRow = «function(A) {
        ....
        return BaseRow;
    }»(utils);
    ....
    ....
    var myTable = .....

    //<--This is require call and therefore doesn't return a thing
    (function(MyTable) {
        jQuery.fn.myTable = function(options) {
            var table = new MyTable(this, options);
            this.data('myTable', table);
            return this;
        };
    })(myTable);
})();
```

As a result of this process, I decided to check things out and combined manually all the files to one minified file. I end up with a file smaller by 3k then the almond version!
I don't find the logic behind the r.js optimizer creating require.js dependent result. In my case, no one will need to use any of the files, my primary js file is the only consumer. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the **findNestedDependencies** option in the optimizer is "false", meaning that even after the scripts are optimized, there could still be a nested `require` or `define` call that would require a module loader. A loader is also needed for external dependencies.

I agree, however, that if findNestedDependencies is set to "true" and no external dependencies are part of the project, the optimizer should be able to remove its need for a loader.

Answer (score -1):

You can just include the files needed in the file. You can do that with a getScript call.

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){

   //whatever you want here.

});
```